Using Github private runners to access azure resources behind VNET causes runner to not have internet connection
So I have a some resources behind a vnet such as a database and soon a storage container. To allow github to be able to deploy via github actions and reach these resources for their build steps and what not I followed this tutorial to add a private github hosted runners with azure integration:
https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/admin/configuring-settings/configuring-private-networking-for-hosted-compute-products/configuring-private-networking-for-github-hosted-runners-in-your-enterprise
The issue is when running my github actions and using this runner its as though the node_modules are not downloading. When I switched from npm to yarn I would get an error showing network issues:
Run yarn install
yarn install v1.22.22
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error AggregateError [ETIMEDOUT]: 
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1118:18)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1186:5)
    at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1712:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I am not a 100 percent sure how it all works but if the runner is in the VNET maybe I need to enable internet access in the VNET somehow so it can access resources like npm and yarn repos to get their packages downloaded? Maybe I need to add a firewall in place or change inbound/outbound settings of my network security group that tutorials .bicep file creates?

To access the azure resource within Vnet, there are ways, 1.Create VM with same Vnet and Subnet and setup the  self-hosted runners inside the VM to access azure resources, follow the doc about selfhosted runner


create P2S VPN to access the azure resources via securely from your laptop, follow the stack link & MS Doc about P2S VPN Configuration in VM


I allowed outbound traffic for the vnet and it fixed the issue. Not sure if that’s a big security issue?

If you are using VM, you can allow the outbound traffic using NSG rule.


Using Github private runners to access azure resources behind VNET causes runner to not have internet connection.

The error you encountered is due to networking restrictions. If you are running the self-hosted runners inside an Azure VM, you may need to allow outbound traffic to access Azure resources
Here is the steps to allow the outbound traffic from VM using NSG.
1.Go to Azure portal > Network security group > Select your VM added NSG >  Outbound security rules

Once you create a outbound rule with ports HTTP and HTTPS, The VM will start communicating to services via 443 and 80.
Refer: Filter network traffic with a network security group using the Azure portal
